# What is the following sign: <<?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does >> do in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921145/what-does-do-in-java)

What does it do this sign: << ? This is in Java.

For an instance, `new CustomPermission(1 << 5, 'M');`

Best regards

Comment: @sepp2k. The answer over there answers this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921145/what-does-do-in-java/3921168#3921168 so yes, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's bitshift

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Basically it multiplies the left operand by 2 to the power of the right operand

so 1 << 5 is 1 * 2^5

Answer (score 1):

its a bit shift operator

this instruction shifts 00000001 five bits to the left: so it becomes 00100000

Answer (score 1):

It's a signed left shift. What you're calculating there is basically 2^5, as you are shifting 00000001 5 times left, which results in 00100000

Answer (score 1):

The '<<' operator shifts all the bits of the number on the left by the value on the right.

For example 1<<5 will be equal to 32.
This is often used in place of multiplication by a power of 2 as in 1<<5 is equivalent to 1*(2^5) or 1*32

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I will also add that bit shifting is commonly used in code which uses bitmasks. So bit 5 in the given code fragment has a specific meaning, which is different to, say bit 3. Using the '<<' operator you can logically combine the different bits to give a combined bitmask.