# Java << Operator

Tags: java, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the following sign: <<?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980218/what-is-the-following-sign)

Can someone please explain the **<<** in the follow sample code?

```
final static public int MY_VAR = 1<<3;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I did not find any hits searching for "java <<".  It seems that '<<' is not searchable??

Comment: "java operators" would give the link posted by lucapette.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, it's a [left shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_shift#Bit_shifts) - you're shifting the number "1" left by 3 bits, so the result will be 8.

See [section 15.19](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19) of the Java Language Specification for more details.

Answer (score 9):

It's the bitwise left-shift operator. It shifts bits to the left, like so:

```
00000001 << 3 == 00001000
```

In other words, `1 << 3 == 8`, since you shift the 1 bit over by 3 places.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bitshift operator. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html for docs.

Answer (score 3):

> **The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left**,
>   and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the
>   right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the
>   number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned
>   right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position,
>   while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

[[Source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)]

Answer (score 2):

`<<` the [left shift operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5121).

Basically it moves every bit in the left-hand value to the left by an amount indicated by the right-hand value.

So `0b1` (decimal 1) becomes `0b1000` (decimal 8) in this example.

It's explained in [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and illustrated in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift).

Answer (score 0):

It's 2 raised to the power of 3.
It's a bitwise operator SHIFT_LEFT: 0001 => 0100